# Download with aria2 from a server with authentication

Tags: download, wget, aria2

I have a file on a server under my account and I need to download it. Let us say that the url is `http://my.server/files/myfile`. I need to authenticate with username and password. I can do that with `wget` as follows

```
 wget http://username:password@my.server/files/myfile
```

and it works. However, trying the same thing with `aria2`

```
 aria2c http://username:password@my.server/files/myfile
```

fails with error message

```
-> [HttpSkipResponseCommand.cc:211] errorCode=24 Authorization failed.
```

Is there a way to fix this? I have also tried `--http-user` and `--http-passwd` options with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Nick, unfortunately not. The problem seems to be that aria2c does not support http digest authentication, according to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151494/issues-with-aria2c-and-basic-auth-wget-working

Comment: Just testet with aria2c 1.31.0, it works.

Comment: Does aria2c support `wget  "https://mysite/data/" --header "Authorization: Bearer amF5YW1ldDphbUY1WVcMGViYzg1" -P .`

Answer (score 0):

`aria2c http://username:password@my.server/files/myfile` command should work if the server uses `Basic Auth`. Since it doesn't work for you, while `wget http://username:password@my.server/files/myfile` does, most likely the server uses some other authorization protocol that `wget` supports (but not `aria2c`), namely `Digest Auth` or `NTLM Auth`: see this [curl comparison table](https://curl.se/docs/comparison-table.html).